# How can I add margin between three Bootstrap columns without them wrapping?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, margin

```css
.background-color {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 background-color">1</div>
    <div class="col-4 background-color">2</div>
    <div class="col-4 background-color">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have three columns which are each 4 columns in width and whenever I add m-3 (margin all around) they break off because of that, how can I contain them? So they stay all 3 on the same line?

```css
.background-color {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 background-color m-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-4 background-color m-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-4 background-color m-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I saw around this was to nest other elements.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><div class="col-12 background-color m-3">1</div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="col-12 background-color m-3">2</div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="col-12 background-color m-3">3</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the point of the inner column classes?

Comment: It'll allow control over the spacing between columns.  The outer columns act as an invisible constraint to build the 3 column row he wants and will keep 3 columns regardless of what happens inside each one, because the margins are not being applied to them but to the inner ones. The inner ones control the look he wants without breaking the flex layout of those 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks feels a bit like a dirty workaround, but it did the job.

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap column system (as you probably know) is based on the idea that the page has 12 notional columns. You then use the col-* classes to indicate how many of those 12 columns each element takes up. So, in this case, you've declared that each element takes up 4 columns, which means they use all 12 notional columns.

The problem is that margins in HTML are *outside* the element. So, if you have three elements, each using 4 columns, and then add some margin, you now have more than the width of the 12 columns available (here, 12 columns plus three lots of m-3). As a result, the third element doesn't have enough space to be displayed and flows to the next line.

To avoid this, you can use padding instead of margins (because paddings are *inside* the element, you get visual separation while sticking to the grid widths). Alternatively, you could reduce the width of the elements to col-3 and add your margin outside that. However, this may mean (depending on your layout) that it doesn't use the full width.

Ultimately, if you need three elements across the page with margins, it may be best to define your own classes rather than trying to use the Bootstrap classes. Frameworks are great when you work with them, and a pain when you work against them!

Comment: Yep thanks, and what about using class="container-fluid" instead of class="container"?

Comment: You could use `container-fluid` if you wanted, but mixing flexbox with grid in your layout may cause other problems. You've accepted the answer involving nesting your structures in HTML, I see, which will work but is inelegant (IMO) and adds code complexity. Personally, as I said, I'd be looking to define my own classes based on the Bootstrap templates.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.background-color {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col background-color m-3 ">1
    </div>
    <div class="col background-color  m-3">2</div>
    <div class="col background-color  m-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

use col instead of col-4

Comment: To clarify, this makes the columns use flexbox principles instead of percentages.